# Plotting a cell array

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, cell-array

I need to plot a cell array with the following format in Matlab:

```
{[vector1], [vector2], ...}
```

Into a 2D graph with the index of the vector as the y and the vector as the x

```
([vector1], 1), ([vector2], 2), ...
```

Comment: Can you actually give us some real data so we can see what you're talking about? Your explanation isn't very clear.

Comment: So each _y_ value has an associated _vector_ of _x_ values? How is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple option:

```
% some arbitrary data:
CellData = {rand(10,1)*50,rand(10,1)*50,rand(10,1)*50};

% Define x and y:
x = cell2mat(CellData);
y = ones(size(x,1),1)*(1:size(x,2));

% plot:
plot(x,y,'o')
ylim([0 size(x,2)+1])
```

so you plot each vector of `x` on a separate `y`  value:

[image: A cell plot]

It will work as long as your cell array is just a list of vectors.

**EDIT: For non equal vectors**

You'll have to use a for loop with `hold`:

```
% some arbitrary data:
CellData = {rand(5,1)*50,rand(6,1)*50,rand(7,1)*50,rand(8,1)*50,rand(9,1)*50};

figure;
hold on
for ii = 1:length(CellData)
    x = CellData{ii};
    y = ones(size(x,1),1)*ii;
    plot(x,y,'o')
end
ylim([0 ii+1])
hold off
```

[image: Cell plot 2]

Hope this answers your question ;)

Comment: My vectors are different sizes so cell2mat(Celldata) does not work

Answer (score 1):

Here's my (brute force) interpretation of your request. There are likely more elegant solutions.

This code generates a dot plot that puts the values from the vectors at each index on the y axis—bottom to top. It can accommodate vectors of different lengths. You could make it a dot plot of vector distributions, but you might need to add some jitter to the x value, if multiple occurrences of identical or nearly identical values are possible.

```
% random data--three vectors from range 1:10 of different lengths
for i = 1:3
    dataVals{i} = randi(10,randi(10,1),1);
end

dotSize = 14;
% plot the first vector with dots and increase the dot size
% I happen to like filled circles for this, and this is how I do it.
h = plot(dataVals{1}, ones(length(dataVals{1}), 1),'.r');
set(h,'markers', dotSize);

ax = gca;  
axis([0 11 0 4]);  % set axis limits
% set the Y axis labels to whole numbers
ax.YTickLabel = {'','','1','','2','','3','','',}';

hold on;
% plot the rest of the vectors
for i=2:length(dataVals)
    h = plot(dataVals{i}, ones(length(dataVals{i}),1)*i,'.r');
    set(h, 'markers', dotSize);
end
hold off
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without any data this is the best I can come up with for what you want:

```
yourCell = {[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2]}; % 1x3 cell
figure; 
plot(cell2mat(yourCell));
ylabel('Vector Values'); 
xlabel('Index of Vector');
```

It makes a plot like this:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why did you swapped the `x` and `y` axis? He wanted the vector index to be as a `y` axis.

Comment: @EBH I think I must have mixed up this question and another one I was answering, oops. I changed my answer. Sorry.