# Matlab: Plot non-equal matrices in a cell array without a loop

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-figure

### Knowing that:

There are a lot of discussion about plotting equal sized matrices in a cell array and it is quite easy to do without a loop.

For example, to plot the 2-by-2 matrices in `mycell`:

```
mycell = {[1 1; 2 1], [1 1; 3 1], [1 1; 4 1]};
```

We can use `cellfun` to add a row of `NaN` at the bottom of each matrix and then convert the cell to a matrix:

```
mycellnaned = cellfun(@(x) {[x;nan(1,2)]}, mycell);
mymat = cell2mat(mycellnaned');
```

`mymat` looks like:

```
     1   1   1   1   1 
     2   1   3   1   4 
    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Then we can plot it easily:

```
mymatx = mymat(:,1:2:end);
mymaty = mymat(:,2:2:end);
figure;
plot(mymatx, mymaty,'+-');
```

---

### The problem:

The problem is now, how do I do something similar with a cell containing non-equal matrices? Such as:

```
mycell = {
    [1:2; ones(1,2)]';
    [1:4; ones(1,4)*2]';
    [1:6; ones(1,6)*3]';
    [1:8; ones(1,8)*4]';
    [1:10; ones(1,10)*5]';
    [1:12; ones(1,12)*6]';
    };

mycell = repmat(mycell,1000,1);
```

I would not be able to convert them into one matrix like I did before. I could use a loop, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38419519/1786137), but it would be very inefficient if the cell contains thousands of matrices.

Therefore, I'm looking for a more efficient way of plotting non-equal sized matrices in a cell array.

**Note** that different colours should be used for different matrices in the figure.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the line following "The `mymat` looks like:" given what came just before. Why are there only 2's in that concatenated array?

Comment: Much better, thanks

Comment: @MadPhysicist nice catch, I fixed it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, while I was writing the question, I figured it out...

I'd like to keep the question open since there might be better solutions.

For everyone else's reference, the solution is simple: add `NaN` to make the matrices equal sized:

```
% find out the maximum length of all matrices in the array
cellLengthMax = max(cellfun('length', mycell));

% fill the matrices so they are equal in size.
mycellfilled = cellfun(@(x) {[
    x
    nan(cellLengthMax-size(x,1), 2)
    nan(1, 2)
    ]}, mycell);
```

Then convert to a matrix and plot:

```
mymat = cell2mat(mycellfilled');
mymatx = mymat(:,1:2:end);
mymaty = mymat(:,2:2:end);

figure;
plot(mymatx, mymaty,'+-');
```

`mymat` looks like:

```
     1     1     1     2     1     3     1     4     1     5     1     6
     2     1     2     2     2     3     2     4     2     5     2     6
   NaN   NaN     3     2     3     3     3     4     3     5     3     6
   NaN   NaN     4     2     4     3     4     4     4     5     4     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     5     3     5     4     5     5     5     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     6     3     6     4     6     5     6     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     7     4     7     5     7     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     8     4     8     5     8     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     9     5     9     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    10     5    10     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    11     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN    12     6
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

[image]

### Update:

> Time cost for plotting 6000 matrices:
>
> using the solution proposed here: 1.183546 seconds.
>
> using a loop: 3.450423 seconds.

Still not very satisfactory. I really wish to reduce the time to 0.1 seconds, because I'm trying to design an interactive UI, where the user can change a few parameters and the result get plotted instantly.

I don't want to reduce the resolution of the figure.

### Update:

I did a profiler and it seems the 99% of the time is wasted on `plot(mymatx, mymaty,'+-');`. So the conclusion is, there is probably no other way to fasten this.

Comment: That's what I was going to post, sloppier (as in yours is neater). I would go ahead and select your own answer on this one.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think I will keep the question open for a while since the time cost is still not satisfactory ;P

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always change the selection once something better comes along.